# Segue performing on separate button click

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, segue

I'm following a course online, the app I'm building is basically a cut down version of Instagram as you can see on the left hand side I have a view for signing in, on the right hand side I have a view for signing up.

Pretty straight forward right, now I have created a `Seque` from the signin page from the button `Register` which when pressed takes you to the registration view (one on the right), this works as expected however if I'm on the signin page and click sign in and it errors for whatever reason I display the error message but straight after is performs the `Seque` to the registration screen even though I never pressed `register`

This is my storyboard:

[image]

This is my code behind the `Sign In` button located on the left view

```
 @IBAction func btnSignIn(sender: AnyObject) {

    if txtUsername.text == "" || txtPassword.text == "" {

        displayAlert("Error", message: "Username and Password required!")

    }
}
```

I have no other code inside this controller which would cause the `Seque` to initialise.

If someone can shed some light into how I can stop this `Seque` from happening on `Sign In` click and only happen when I press `Register` I'd appreciate it.

**Update**

After further investigation this seems to be an issue with my alert box I'm displaying.  If I comment out the alert box and press signin and let it error yet not display anything then click register which takes me to the view on the right, click sign in and get taken back to view on the left and then press `Sign In` display the alert box and when it closes it seems like it thinks the view controller that's being displayed in the one previous to the current one on the page, which is odd.  This is my alert function:

```
  func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) { // Display alert message to user.  Passing in title and message which will be displayed.

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let a = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        a.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        })))

        self.presentViewController(a, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `displayAlert`?  You say "errors for any reason"; are there any other checks aside from the text field being empty or is that all you have at this point?

Comment: @Paulw11 just added it, after some more investigation.

Comment: You don't need to dismiss the alert view controller in the action. When the user selects an action, the alert controller is automatically dismissed. Since you are calling `dismissViewController` you are going back to the previous view controller

Comment: Can you upload a copy of your project? Some of the relevant things here might be a part of the storyboard and not the direct code, so it would be a lot easier to troubleshoot if we have the whole project.

Comment: @Paulw11 you're right that seemed to off worked.  Please put your comment as the answer and I'll mark it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to dismiss the alert view controller in the action. When the user selects an action, the alert controller is automatically dismissed.

Since you are calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` you are going back to the previous view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Sign-in button and check Connections Inspector, may be you have copy-pasted these two buttons so the action of both sign-in and register button would be same.

Comment: Nope, never copied and pasted. I did check the connections inspector just encase something happened.